# Using LINQ to group numbers

Tags: c#, linq, functional-programming

Suppose if I have a list of numbers like this,

```
   [3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2]
```

and I'd like to group them together in a sequence such that the sum of each group is less or equal to five, i.e. the correct answer is:

```
  [3], [3, 1], [2,3], [2]
```

Is there a way to express this using Linq?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Easy.

```
var results = xs.Aggregate<int, List<List<int>>>(
    new List<List<int>> { new List<int>() },
    (a, n) =>
    {
        if (a.Last().Sum() + n > 5)
        {
            a.Add(new List<int> { n });
        }
        else
        {
            a.Last().Add(n);
        }
        return a;
    });
```

So, from this:

```
var xs = new [] { 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, };
```

I get this:

[image: result]

Comment: Very very cunning. I like it. The only potential downside is the repeated summing of previous values in the Last() List for each step forward. Might be slow for a large target group sum (say 10000), but fine for this case where the target is 5.

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if this is anywhere close to what you had in mind, but lets give it a go

```
List<int> l = new List<int> { 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2 };
int[] index = {0};
var s = l.Select((k, i) =>
{
    if (i < index[0])
        return null;

    int total = 0;
    return l.Skip(index[0]).TakeWhile(x =>
    {
        total += x;
        if (total <= 5)
            index[0]++;
        return total <= 5;
    });
}).Where(x => x != null);

foreach (IEnumerable<int> e in s)
{
    foreach (int i in e)
    {
        Console.Write("{0},", i);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

My reasoning was as follows,

1. We have to go through all the items, so therefor the select.
2. we have to takes items from the list until the total is reached, so therefor the TakeWhile
3. We have to track where we got to in the list, so therefor the index and the return null.

I tried using `int index = 0;` initialy, but Resharper moaned about *access to modified closure* and recomended changing it to `int[] index = {0};`

Answer (score 0):

You could try an extension method (something like this, tested with your example, but not a lot more testing than that!):

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> GroupsLessThan(this IEnumerable<int> source, int target)
    {
        var list = new List<int>();
        var runningCount = 0;
        foreach (var element in source)
        {
            if (runningCount + element < target)
            {
                list.Add(element);
                runningCount += element;
            }
            else
            {
                yield return list;
                runningCount = element;
                list = new List<int>{element};
            }
        }

        if (list.Count > 0)
        {
            yield return list;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage then looks like this:

```
var array = new int[] { 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2 };
var list = array.GroupsLessThan(6).ToList();
```